# Python looping and appending arrays

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I'm creating an application to test how many 'steps' it takes for a number to reach 1 using the colatz conjecture. Here is the code:

```
import sys
import csv

def findSteps(mode):
    count = 0
    while mode != 1:
        count = count + 1
        if mode%2 == 0:
            mode = mode/2
        else:
            mode = (3*mode)+1

    return count

numbers = []
counts = []

for n in range(1, 100):
    important = findSteps(n)
    numbers[n] = n
    counts[n] = important

with open('colatz conjecture table.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    myWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    myWriter.writerow(numbers)
    myWriter.writerow(counts)
```

Unfortunately, whenever I run it, it gives me a "Index Error: List Assignment out of range."

Comment: `numbers[n] = n`: you can't simply assign to a random index in a list, if the list isn't of the correct size. Please read up some more on lists in Python. Perhaps you want a dict?

Comment: build up your list by appending: `counts.append(important)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition of the `list.append()` variant, you may also use

```
numbers = range(1, 100)
counts = [findSteps(n) for n in numbers]
```

Or, if you like to keep it functional

```
numbers = range(1, 100)
counts = map(findSteps, numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `numbers` and `counts` have a type of `list`, based on how you defined them in your code. So you can use the method of `append` to add the data to both of them. Just remember that the indexes are zero-based.
Moreover, I agree with @Evert's comment it looks like a `dictionary` object is better suited for your needs.